# Finding adjoint of a Matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, adjoint-operators

For $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$, write down the adjoint of $$\alpha_1\left|V_1\right\rangle=\alpha_2 \Theta \Pi\left|V_2\right\rangle\left\langle V_3 \mid V_4\right\rangle+\alpha_3^*\left|V_5\right\rangle+\alpha_4 \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \left|\alpha_5^*V_5\right\rangle$$,

Where $\Theta, \Pi,\Lambda$ are matrices and $\left|V_1\right\rangle, \left|V_2\right\rangle, \left|V_3\right\rangle, \left|V_4\right\rangle,\left|V_5\right\rangle
$
are Ket vectors.

I only know to find ad-joint of matrices that I understood from my school days, and using this I know to find the inverse of matrices.
I also have some ideas about Matrix representation in quantum mechanics, Dirac-Ket notation etc.
Could anyone please give some hints to move forward?